# Why is my pause button not working when designing a timer using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm new to javascript. The following code is my practice for designing a timer. It works for the start button when clicked, but not for the pause button. I've spent hours trying to figure it out, but I still have no clue. Any help would be highly appreciated!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
      <div class="inputs" id="inputs-div">
        <input id="hours" type="number" name="hours" max="100" min="0" value="1"/>
        <input id="minutes" type="number" name="minutes" max="59" min="0" value="10"/>
      </div>

      <div class="countdown-div">
         <input id="countdownTimer" type="text" style="display: none" />
      </div>

      <div class="buttons">
        <button id="button-start">Start</button>
        <button id="button-pause">Pause</button>
        <button id="button-cancel" style="display: none">Cancel</button>
        <button id="button-resume" style="display: none">Resume</button>
      </div>

      <script>
         var hours = document.getElementById("hours").value,
             mins = document.getElementById("minutes").value,
             maxtime = parseInt(hours) * 3600 + parseInt(mins) * 60;

         document.getElementById("button-start").addEventListener("click", myFunction);

         function myFunction() {
            document.getElementById("button-start").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("button-cancel").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("inputs-div").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("countdownTimer").style.display = "block";  
         }



         function timedCount() {

           document.getElementById('countdownTimer').value=Math.floor(maxtime/3600)+":"
           +Math.floor(maxtime%3600/60)+":"+maxtime % 3600 % 60;
           maxtime--;
           setTimeout("timedCount()",1000);
         }

         var t=setTimeout("timedCount()",1000);

         function timerPause() {
            clearTimeout(t);
         }

         document.getElementById("button-pause").addEventListener("click", timerPause);

       </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Off topic but helpful: 1) avoid global variables 2) `addEventListener` expects 3 arguments, not 2 (though, granted, these days most browsers will forgive you for its omission.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the line `setTimeout("timedCount()",1000);` inside your `timedCount()` function.

You need to assign it to `t` so you can still clear it.  Also, I don't know why your function names are in strings when you do `setTimeout`, I'm not sure if that works.  Usually you just put the function name without `()`

```
 function timedCount() {
       document.getElementById('countdownTimer').value=Math.floor(maxtime/3600)+":"
       +Math.floor(maxtime%3600/60)+":"+maxtime % 3600 % 60;
       maxtime--;
       t = setTimeout(timedCount,1000); <--- this line
 }
```

You should really look into `setInterval` and `clearInterval`.

Comment: Thanks, Dave, for your quick reply. Actually, the function names in strings are OK, I've tested it in the js fiddle. Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: @user3854649—passing a string to *setTimeout* is considered poor practice as it results in a call to the Function constructor, as if you'd written `setTimeout(new Function('countDownTimer()'),1000)`. Much better to just pass a function reference as in dave's answer.

Comment: @RobG, thanks for clarifying dave's suggestion. Now I get a better sense of invoking funcitons.